# file_get_contents() disabled for security reasons

Tags: php

I'm not able to run this PHP code. According to [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/).

`file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons on line number 2`

Is there any way to skip it? yesterday it worked, I have no idea why now doesn't work.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
echo $details;
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's disabled at `phptester.net`. You still can use it on your own server.

Comment: I get this error with XAMPP and phptester.net

"E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR : type 4096 -- Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string -- at line 5"

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of [`json_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). The string that you're trying to pass expects it to be JSON and the argument won't be understood; it just needs the IP address.

You can then grab the JSON output from there, if that is what you're really after.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'd like to get only the country code. Should I remove the json decode() anyway? if so, please can you fix the code?
Thank you.

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
echo $details->country; // -> "US"

Comment: Fetching the data to be placed into an array, is a different question than what you posted and the error message that you got from running it. You can run a `print_r()` from it. Decoding is another ballgame.

Answer (score 1):

According to **ipinfo.io**,  if you want only country code then you can pass it to url...

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/country");
echo $details;
```

Output

```
IN
```

Or your IP country code.

Test code [here](http://phpfiddle.org)

Read ipinfo.io documents [here](https://ipinfo.io/developers)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.